# Having problems with function definition in python

Tags: python, function-definition

```
def prompt(n):
    value=int(input("Please enter integer #", n ,":" , sep=""))
    return value

value1=prompt(1)
```

error:

> value=int(input("Please enter integer #", n ,":" , sep="")) TypeError:
>   input() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: The parameters you have provided look like they are intended for `print()`.  They are meaningless for `input()`.

Comment: how to get output like:' Please enter integer #1:' for prompt(1) ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `input()` built-in function in python takes only 1 parameter - *prompt*. Please refer to the python documentation for [input function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

Edit: As per your comment, you need to update your prompt to include the parameter that you've sent. See the code below. As chris mentioned in the comments, the f-strings will work only in Python versions 3.6

```
def prompt(n): 
    value=int(input(f"Please enter integer {}".format(n))) 
    return value
```

For Python versions < 3.6, you can you use the old formatting strings as shown in the code below

```
def prompt(n): 
    value=int(input("Please enter integer {}".format(n))) 
    return value
```

Comment: yeah, its working now. can you refer to an updated document on function definitions in python.

Comment: It would be good to mention that _f-formatting_ is only supported in python 3.6 or above.

Comment: @Abhi There are good ol' _%-formatting_ as well as `str.format()`.

Comment: seems like the book from where i am learning python is outdated